# Why is jQuery .html generating an extra element before replacing the original element in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cart

I'm trying to update the cart status when a product is added to the cart.

When I click the "Add to cart" button, it runs:

```
$(".cart-text").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/cart_text') %>")
```

This strangely generates a new DOM element and then starts updating that new element, instead of replacing the contents of the original element. See the problem in action here:

https://gyazo.com/f3781639b0c8d4008bb38428f6c783bd

Here's my current code:

https://github.com/davidalejandroaguilar/simple-cart

**EDIT:**

**Application Layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Workspace</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<% flash.each do |key,value| %>
<%= content_tag :div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}" %>
<% end %>

<p class="cart-text">
<%= render 'layouts/cart_text' %>
</p>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**Create.js.erb in views/order_items**

```
$(".cart-text").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/cart_text') %>")
```

**OrderItems Controller**

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.build(order_item_params)
    @order.save
    session[:order_id] = @order.id
  end

  def update
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.update_attributes(order_item_params)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def destroy
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.destroy
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  def order_item_params
    params.require(:order_item).permit(:product_id, :quantity)
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you point out where is your code? givin all repo is hard to see what's happen.

Comment: Sorry @weigreen, I thought it'd be better in case the problem lies somewhere else... what code would be best to include in the question?

Comment: This basically just inserts your partial into the view.  You should add a jquery hide effect that removes whatever element this is intended to replace.  Assuming I understood the question that is.

Comment: Hey @bkunzi01, jQuery's API indicates that ".html" replaces the content, so I thought it had to be something else. "When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest `<p>` tags (https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1). It creates an invalid DOM. You can look it up in your browser's inspector.

Removing the `<p>` from `layouts/cart_text` should fix the problem.

Comment: Nice! I was sure it had to be something simple! Let this be a lesson for beginners like me. Not sure what I should be seeing in my inspector though... nothing seemed odd there except for the extra element.